# C#, S22.Imap: Negative search for UIDs impossible for first condition?

Tags: c#, .net, email, imap

I would like to create such search setup:

```
IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search( // trying to find all NOT backup emails
  SearchCondition.Not(SearchCondition.From("given-sender@gmail.com").And(
  SearchCondition.Subject("BackupMail")))
);
```

But if fails with:

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'S22.Imap.SearchCondition.Not(S22.Imap.SearchCondition)'
```

Also, what is strange, following is just fine (programmatically, but without any sense):

```
IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search( // trying to find all NOT backup emails
  SearchCondition.From("blabla@gmail.com").Not(SearchCondition.From("given-sender@gmail.com").And(
  SearchCondition.Subject("BackupMail")))
);
```

So... am I right here, that I can negate only second (and after) part of this method?

Comment: [`SearchCondition.Not`](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap/blob/master/SearchCondition.cs#L328) is an instance method. Try `SearchCondition.All().Not(...)`

Comment: Sorry mate, it's compiling but returning nothing. If I search for All() only - I get all mails from that mailbox, so I think it is impossible to get at same tame "all mails from mailbox" AND "only mails meeting conditions"